# Responsive menu toggler does not work

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, mobile-menu

I am using a custom theme with blank as parent. Everything works well but I noticed that on responsive screens the hamburger menu seems broken. When I click on it nothing happens while I expect the navigation menu to show up.

```
The version of the Magento installation is 2.2.5
I tried inheriting the menu.js and extended only the toggle function but still it does not work
```

Is there anyone who has experienced the same issue and can give some advice?

!UPDATE!
event handler is not attached to the element! It is though attached only on login screen and there the button works properly

[image]

Comment: can you describe with screen shot.

Comment: @AakashJoshi Please review again the question as i updated it!

Comment: I just review snap, I have observed this issue is related to jquery.
can you please tell me verify is there any js related error in browser console window?

Comment: Unfortunately i get no errors! What i can tell though is that the menu.js is not loaded. I saw that from the network monitor that everything is being fetched from responsive.js , matchMedia.js but not menu.js!

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same problem and it turned out to be because we had recently enabled Varnish Cache.

Comment: And... did you get an actual solution?